# Oracle: Copy Database Oracle 10.2.0.2 to Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle12c

Currently we have a database running on Oracle 10g (10.2.0.2) in production which needs to be up 24/7, but since it is not supported by the data center, both server OS and Oracle database 10g, we have to move to Oracle 12c as agreed by the superiors. I know I can't use a direct expdp/impdp from 10.2.0.2 to 12.2.0.1. And with limited resources, meaning server resources and no access to oracle support to download oracle 10.2.0.5 patch set or any patch set that is available.

What is the safest and best way with minimal downtime option to move it from 10g to 12c? Do I need to install an 11gR2 software and use it to expdp the data?

Answer (score 0):

The impdp should be downward compatible, but what you can do is:

> 1. Do the expdp of your 10.2 database with the 12c software
> 2. Use the VERSION parameter of expdp and impdp if you still have problems

You have not told us how big your 10.2 database is and whether you have a limited budget or not.  Sometimes the 'superiors' want every last transaction accounted for, and the only way to do this is to use Goldengate.  So you can setup the target database, take as long as you need to import the data, and all the while goldengate is keeping the source and target in synch.  Goldengate is expensive though and should only be necessary if you have terabytes to deal with.